# UIImageView cuts inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uiview, uikit

I'm trying to create `UIScrollView` With `UIStackView` that contains multiple `UIImageView` with this code:

```
let stackView = UIStackView(frame: .zero)

scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scrollView.backgroundColor = .green
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
scrollView.delegate = self

self.view.addSubview(scrollView)


scrollView.anchor(top: textSV.bottomAnchor, leading: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: anotherView?.topAnchor, trailing: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true

scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never

stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
stackView.spacing = 0

scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.fillSuperview()

for _ in 1...8 {
    let pageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "iphone12mockup"))
    pageView.clipsToBounds = true
    pageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    pageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(pageView)

    pageView.anchor(top: stackView.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: stackView.bottomAnchor, trailing: nil)
}
```

The problem is that the UIImageView does not resize to `scaleAspectFit` and it looks like this(Can't see full image):

[image]

## EDIT

```
let img = UIImage(named: "iphone12mockup")
let width = img?.size.width

let pageView = UIImageView(image: img)
pageView.clipsToBounds = true
pageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

pageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.addArrangedSubview(pageView)

pageView.anchor(top: stackView.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: stackView.bottomAnchor, trailing: nil)
pageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width!).isActive = true
```

Comment: You need to explicitly set the width of the `UIImageView` if you don't want it to scroll horizontally, as there's nothing to "fit" to inside a scroll view.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I update my code and I still get the same result(You can see the edit under my post)

Comment: You're constraining it to the image width - that won't change anything. You need to constrain it to the width of the scroll view container (i.e. what you're doing now with `UIScreen.main.bounds.width`). 

The whole point of a scroll view is that you can have larger content inside that you can scroll, so you can't expect a image not to take up all the necessary space if you don't constrain at least one dimension.

Comment: Also you really shouldn't use `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` to constrain the width, it's a) bad practice, and b) will fail when you rotate the device. Just constrain it to `self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor`, that way you get the safe insets in landscape mode (i.e. the scroll-view won't go behind the notch)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I want that that imageview will be next each other and without paging, and I want them to fit to the scrollview height

Comment: You're still not understanding how the scroll view works, I'd recommend you spend some time reading up about it. Also, it sounds like what you really need is a `UIPageViewController` and not a custom scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make use of the scroll view's Content and Frame Layout Guides...

- constrain all 4 sides of the stack view to the scroll view's **Content Layout Guide**
- constrain the stack view's Height to the scroll view's **Frame Layout Guide**

for each image view you add to the stack view:

- constrain the image view's Width to the scroll view's **Frame Layout Guide**

Here is a complete example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // just trying to include what you've shown
        let textSV = UILabel()
        textSV.backgroundColor = .yellow
        textSV.text = "textSV"
        textSV.textAlignment = .center
        
        let anotherView = UILabel()
        anotherView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        anotherView.text = "anotherView"
        anotherView.textAlignment = .center
        
        [textSV, anotherView].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        
        // respect safe area
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textSV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor),
            textSV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor),
            textSV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor),
            textSV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),

            anotherView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor),
            anotherView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor),
            anotherView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor),
            anotherView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
        ])

        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .green
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.delegate = self

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // use a stack view to hold and arrange the scrollView's subviews
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // add the stackView to the scrollView
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        // use scrollView's Content Layout Guide to define scrollable content
        let layoutG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        // use scrollView's Frame Layout Guide to define content height (since you want horizontal scrolling)
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain scrollView Top to textSV Bottom
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textSV.bottomAnchor),
            
            // constrain scrollView Leading/Trailing to safe area
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor),
            
            // constrain scrollView Bottom to anotherView Top
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anotherView.topAnchor),
            
            // constrain all 4 sides of the stackView to scrollView's Content Layout Guide
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutG.topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutG.bottomAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutG.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutG.trailingAnchor),
            
            // constrain stackView's height to scrollView's Frame Layout Guide height
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.heightAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // add imageViews to the stack view
        for _ in 1...8 {
            let pageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "iphone12mockup"))
            //let pageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "sample"))
            // set image view background color so you can
            //  see its frame (since the image will be aspect-fit scaled)
            pageView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
            pageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            // add it to the stack view
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(pageView)
            // constrain its Width to scrollView's Frame Layout Guide Width
            pageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        }

    }
    
}
```

It will look like this on startup (on an iPhone 8):

[image]

and after scrolling a little to the right:

[image]

Note that since you want the image view set to `Aspect Fit`, I gave the "pageView" image views a background color of `.systemYellow` so you can see that the imageView frame fills the scroll view frame width and height.

---

**Edit** -- if you want the images to be proportional to their height, without "empty space on the sides," you need to set the image view width constraint proportional to its height, based on the image size.

Replace the "add image views" loop with this:

```
    // add imageViews to the stack view
    for _ in 1...8 {
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "iphone12mockup") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!")
        }
        let pageView = UIImageView()
        pageView.image = img
        pageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        // add it to the stack view
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(pageView)
        // constrain its Width proportional to the image height
        pageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: img.size.width / img.size.height).isActive = true
    }
```

and the output will be:

[image]

and after scrolling a little to the right:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But there is one problem, I want that the imageview will be without any space between them

Comment: @YosiFZ - see the **Edit** in my answer.